# Does the Google bot execute and follow AJAX requests that are bound to an onclick handler?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-crawler, googlebot

Let's say I have a page including a few buttons with JavaScript onclick handlers that perform AJAX requests and insert the returned HTML into the site.

Nothing of this happens automatically on load. The buttons have to be clicked.

Will Google be able to index the content of the remote resources that are fetched via AJAX in the context of the page? In other words: Will Google scan for AJAX requests in my JavaScript and execute them and then include the returned HTML into its scan of the page's content?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: maybe. Some JavaScript is executed but exactly what gets executed and what doesn't depends on Googles algorithm.

Your best bet would be to sign up for webmaster tools and use that to see how google sees your site.

http://www.google.com/webmasters/

**UPDATE**: This question has already been answered: [Do Google's crawlers interpret Javascript? What if I load a page through AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061844/do-googles-crawlers-interpret-javascript-what-if-i-load-a-page-through-ajax)

Comment: I've seen that answer, but my question is different. My AJAX request is only done onclick, so Google shouldn't execute it because it might not be relevant to the page.

Comment: Perhaps you could use Hijax to provide a HTML version of the content that the crawler can see?

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/spiders-view-of-web-20.html

Comment: My problem is directly the opposite. I *don't want* Google to see these resources. It's about avoiding the duplicate content problem.

Comment: Ahh, OK. In that case you could try the solution outlined here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456004/ajax-url-accessed-by-google